# how to send notification on ios using c#

Tags: ios, pushsharp

I am using this code which I mention below but I am getting an error:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: Your Certificate is not a valid certificate for connecting to Apple's APNS servers

I want to send notification using asp.net MVC to iOS device. I am using push sharp library to send a notification.

Answer (score 1):

here you go, also you need to pay attention if your certificate is Prod/Dev
depending that in the `ApplePushChannelSettings` method your first argument is true= if certificate is  production
false = if certificate is  development

```
broker = new PushBroker();
broker.OnNotificationSent += _broker_OnNotificationSentApple;
broker.OnChannelException += _broker_OnChannelExceptionApple;
broker.OnServiceException += _broker_OnServiceExceptionApple;
broker.OnNotificationFailed += _broker_OnNotificationFailedApple;
broker.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += _broker_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpiredApple;
broker.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += _broker_OnDeviceSubscriptionChangedApple;
broker.OnChannelCreated += _broker_OnChannelCreatedApple;
broker.OnChannelDestroyed += _broker_OnChannelDestroyedApple;


byte[] appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(the path to the certificate);
broker.RegisterAppleService(new PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushChannelSettings(false,appleCert, appCertPassword,false),null);/

broker.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                         .ForDeviceToken(yourDeviceToken)
                         .WithAlert(message)
                         .WithBadge(0));
```